# How to give feedback to the Windows product team?

Tags: windows

I’d like to make a suggestion to improve Windows in a specific way. How can I register my suggestion with the Windows product team? Is there a publicly available feedback channel? Does the product have a feedback feature?

The Windows 10 beta program is closed. Microsoft Connect does not appear to have a section for the Windows OS. They do not appear to use [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Windows 10 (PC/Mobile) you can install the [Feedback Hub](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/app/9nblggh4r32n) App and send Feedback to Microsoft.

> Help us make Windows better! Provide feedback about Windows and apps
>   by sharing your suggestions or problems.

[image]

Comment: Cool! Maybe there is a way for Windows 7, too? (I intentionally did not tie the question to a Windows version.)

Comment: for Windows 7, there is no way and MS no longer listens to your Win7 issues it is in extended support and only gets security fixes.

Comment: @boot4life - Windows 7 is in extended support, so Windows 7, will not receive any additional features or fixes (except security those that are connected to security), Microsoft is not collecting feedback on Windows 7.  Windows 7 licenses are no longer even sold by Microsoft.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you shouldn't need to install it. It came with Windows 10 for me.

Comment: @Carcigenicate the app only comes with the Insider Preview Builds. If you use a normal Windows 10 version you need the to install the app

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not using an insider build. I also just checked my gaming laptop (also W10, non-insider), and it also has it. I don't recall explicitly installing it on either.

Comment: When I upgraded to Windows 10 from 8.1, the app was automatically installed.

Comment: that is interesting. I'm still on Win8 and only use the Insider Build as WinToGo for some testings and here the app is included by default

Answer (score 11):

If you have Windows 10 then go to the search bar.

Type in "Feedback" and a Windows Feedback app should appear.

Click into it then you just sign in and I presume in there is a way to give feedback.

Hope it helps.

Comment: FYI, you need a Microsoft account (free, of course).

Answer (score 6):

When you join the [Windows Insider program](https://insider.windows.com/), you will occasionally receive e-mails from Microsoft that ask you to take a survey. (I've received two or three over the past few months.) You can express your pleasure or displeasure with specific aspects of Windows on varying scales, and there are usually some freeform text fields that you can use to say anything you like.

Answer (score 0):

The Feedback app requires you to downgrade your privacy settings.  It says "Please change your diagnostic and usage data setting to be either: Enhanced or Full.  If you decide not to, we'll miss you".

It is creepy requirement if you have generic feedback that doesn't require Microsoft to sift through your private data.

Comment: Generally, the data that Microsoft gets back is mostly programmings codes, and not your private data.  Yes, once in a while a small segments of a document are included just, because they insect with the code that blew up, not because they are sifting through your document.  Now, if you use OneDrive, that is a whole different story.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)